# How to implement the DebateTree algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, wiki

> The DebateTree algorithm (formerly dialectic algorithm) is a recursive algorithm for computing the status (SUSTAINED or REFUTED) of any argument out of the structure of its debate tree. The algorithm captures the intuitive idea that an argument should be considered refuted when it has unrefuted objections, and sustained otherwise. — [wikiversity.org](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/DebateTree_algorithm)

How to implement this algorithm in LaTeX (preferably not using LuaLaTeX)?

Here's a structure I've been thinking about, an answer doesn't have to conform to it to be accepted, it's just for inspiration.

```latex
\argument{First argument}{
    \objection{First objection}{
        \objection{Counter objection}{}}
    \objection{Second objection}{}}
```

The output could be as follows:

```
(+) F̶i̶r̶s̶t̶ ̶a̶r̶g̶u̶m̶e̶n̶t̶
    (!) F̶i̶r̶s̶t̶ ̶o̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶
        (!) Counter-objection
    (!) Second objection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Typesetting Debates with the Debate Tree Algorithm
% https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/DebateTree_algorithm
\newcommand\DBTsustained{sustained}% define \DBTsustained and \DBTrefuted to be any
\newcommand\DBTrefuted{refuted}    %   two different values, like "sustained" and "refuted"
% \DBTevaluate{ignored}{list of objections}
\newcommand\DBTevaluate[2]{%       % evaluate the objections in #2
  \begingroup                      %
  \let\DBTResult\DBTrefuted        %   assume that all objections can be refuted
  #2%                              %   iterate through the objections, sustained ones will set \DBTResult to \DBTsustained
  \global\let\DBTtmp\DBTResult     %   move the result of the evaluation outside of the group
  \endgroup                        %
  \ifx\DBTtmp\DBTrefuted           %   If all sub-objections have been refuted then
    \let\DBTResult\DBTsustained    %     this argument/objection can be sustained
  \fi                              %   otherwise the status in \DBTResult remains unchanged
}
% \DBTtypeset{\typesetSustained}{\typesetRefuted}{argument}{list of objections}
\newcommand\DBTtypeset[4]{%        % evaluate objections, typeset argument, and then typeset sub-debate
  \let\objection\DBTevaluate       %   set \objection to evaluation mode
  \let\DBTResult\DBTrefuted        %   assume that all objections can be refuted
  #4%                              %   evaluate objections
  \ifx\DBTResult\DBTrefuted        %   if all objections have been refuted
    #1{#3}%                        %     \typesetSustained{argument}
  \else                            %   else
    #2{#3}%                        %     \typesetRefuted{argument}
  \fi                              %   endif
  \def\objection{\DBTtypeset\ObjSustained\ObjRefuted}% set \objection to typesetting mode
  \begin{debate}                   %   typeset sub-debate
    #4%                            %   typeset objections
  \end{debate}
}
\newcommand\objection{}
\newcommand\argument{\DBTtypeset\ArgSustained\ArgRefuted}

% typesetting of sub-debates (= list of objections)
\newenvironment{debate}{%
  \advance\leftskip 2em%
}{}
% typesetinng of arguments and objections, sustained or refuted
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand\ArgSustained[1]{\noindent(+) \textbf{Argument:} #1\par}
\newcommand\ArgRefuted  [1]{\noindent(+) \st{\textbf{Argument:} #1}\par}
\newcommand\ObjSustained[1]{\noindent(!) \textbf{Objection:} #1\par}
\newcommand\ObjRefuted  [1]{\noindent(!) \st{\textbf{Objection:} #1}\par}

\begin{document}

\section*{The debate from the original posting}

\argument{First argument}{
  \objection{First objection}{
    \objection{Counter objection}{}
  }
  \objection{Second objection}{}
}

\section*{The sample debate from Wikiversity}

\argument{Causing unnecessary suffering on animals is morally wrong. Eating or otherwise exploiting animals is unnecessary and causes much suffering. Therefore, eating or otherwise exploiting animals is morally wrong and should be abolished.}{
  \objection{Non-human animals have no feelings and suffer no pain.}{
    \objection{Non-human animals behave very similar to us humans under circumstances that would cause us pain: they scream (or produce other loud noises), shake, contort, run, try to avoid the source of pain, etc.}{}
    \objection{Non-human animals, especially mammals and birds, have a nervous system very similar to our own.}{}
  }
  \objection{Animals in the wild suffer more, as starvation and predation is a constant threat to them. For a natural equilibrium, all animal species living in the wild live at the brink of starvation, as an excess of food leads to their numbers increasing, then collapsing.}{
    \objection{Animals in factory farms suffer guaranteed predation at a fraction of their natural life span. They don't lack food, true, but they are systematically mutilated, exploited, denied of basic freedom of movement, electrocuted, kicked, and many, many, many other atrocities. In traditional farms, animals are denied freedom of movement and reproduction, and also suffer guaranteed predation at a fraction of their natural life span.}{}
  }
}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's perfect, thank you!

Comment: I encourage you to package it to CTAN

Comment: @Victor I have modified my answer a bit: formatting of objection lists is now explicit, and I've added a few comments. Regarding CTAN: we'll see ... In any case this was the funniest challenge in a while here on TeX.SX (for me), so also thanks to you for posting it.